# Anti Money Laundering (AML) information on the beneficial owner for clients of a custodian

Tags: finance, banking, money-laundering, accounting, custody

A custodian bank has a client which is an investment arranger.

The funds of the investment arranger's clients are held at the custodian.

The custodian has flagged one of the investment arranger's clients as being a money laundering risk and has now frozen the individual client's account (including their funds).

The investment arranger's client is understandably upset about this.

In order to avoid 'tipping the customer off', the investment arranger's client should not be given further information regarding this.

Is there any legal reason why the custodian *must* however inform the investment arranger of the details around freezing the investment arranger's client's account?

Comment: I assume that flagging the client means informing the relevant AML authorities.  If so,  in E&W the offence of tipping off depends on the status of the "investment arranger" e.g. is it in the financial regulated sector, within the custodian's supervisory group etc, as defined within [POCA2002](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2002/29/contents)..?

Comment: @Rick Flagging means noticing an AML concern, presumably the custodian would then inform the NCA. The arranger would be regulated, however not associated to the custodian in any way other than as a client, hence not part of the custodian's supervisory group (I assume this is in reference to article 333B of POCA). What do you mean by E&W?

Comment: Thanks - As you mention the NCA, I assume this *hypothetical* question refers to activity in England & Wales (E&W),  or is it Scotland or Northern Ireland?

Comment: @Rick Ah, right. It would be for a company regulated by the FCA which covers all of the UK. Is the Scottish POCA (if there is one) sufficiently similar to the E&W version for the purposes of this scenario, I would assume so. Otherwise yes, the question would be referring to activity specifically in England or Wales.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll get back with an answer later when I have a bit more time to gather my thoughts

Comment: Please spell out acronyms lke AML at least once.

Comment: @ohwilleke done